# Access a spawned process's TIB through FS register?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, winapi

I'd like to access a spawned process's TIB (I created the process with CreateProcessW successfully).

I have obtained a pointer to the spawned process's TIB through:

- GetThreadContext (with permissions set of course)
- Accessing pContext.SegFs
- Formatting this value like so: `(ldtSel.HighWord.Bits.BaseHi << 24 ) | ( ldtSel.HighWord.Bits.BaseMid << 16 ) | ( ldtSel.BaseLow );` (I don't think this is necessary).

The value I am left with after the format is a 10 digit pointer.

How am I to use this variable in place of the fs register to access the threads information block?
The conventional way I would access it generally would be as so:

```
 __asm 
  {
      mov eax, fs:[0x30]  // PEB
      mov dwPebBase, eax
  }
```

However, replacing the "fs" with the pointer variable of course wouldn't work, and removing the semi-colon had unexpected results.
So how can I access the members of the TIB through this pointer value, I feel as if I am accessing memory that isn't supposed to be accessed (or attempting to anyway :P).

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The TIB is in another process's address space, you can't access it from the parent process I'm afraid (but perhaps `ReadProcessMemory` may help).

Comment: You'll need to use [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx). But rather than jumping into how: why do you want to read a TIB from a child process? (Remember there may be more than one thread in the process.)

Comment: okay thank you, ReadProcessMemory seems to be the way to go. I need to access the LDR_MODULE through the PEB, and access the LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList and crawl through the list. I cannot access the thread's TIB normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are taking the wrong approach for this.  Use `NtQueryInformationProcess()` instead of `GetThreadContext()` to access the spawned process's PEB, eg:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
...
PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi = {0};
ULONG pbi_len = 0;
if (NtQueryInformationProcess(pi.hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), &pbi_len) >= 0)
{
    if (pbi.PebBaseAddress)
    {
        PEB peb = {0};
        SIZE_T peb_len = 0;
        if (ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, pbi.PebBaseAddress, &peb, sizeof(peb), &peb_len))
        {
            // use peb as needed...
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to the following article for more info:

[Get Process Info with NtQueryInformationProcess](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19685/Get-Process-Info-with-NtQueryInformationProcess)

Answer (score 0):

a simple trick is call ntdll!RtlGetCurrentPeb() in your local process, this routine return a pointer to PEB, this pointer is in fact valid, and also point to PEB in remote process, then you can use ReadProcessMemory() to read what you need.